# Pseudo Periodic Signal

Tags: signal, signal-integrity, phase

I am reading a research paper [Eyer 1999](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1999A%26AS..136..421E/abstract) in which they used these terms so I want to know about them since there is no source on which I can learn about these terms so that's why asking it here, it might be a simple question but I want to know about Pseudo period and Pseudo periodic signals, what does it mean and how to describe it?

Comment: This is really a question for astronomers. But this [reference](https://www.image.ucar.edu/pub/nychka/manuscripts/jrsscrev.pdf) may help.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought someone will answer me about pseudo periodic signals and pseudo period, I don't know whether these terms are used in Astrophysics only or they are generalized terms?

Comment: I believe the paper I listed discusses the meaning. Do you want me to tell you where and on which page(s)? I could be wrong. But I think the meaning is taken from papers like this one. If you want, I know a few professionals in the field. I could just ask one that is closer to this question, I suppose. (Dr. Guinan should know, I think. It's been a few months since I last talked with him. But I don't think he'd mind.)

Comment: No, I will read this paper but I wanted to know that these terms are specific to only one field of Astrophysics or they are general terms and can be use in any field? I don't want to go in detail, by knowing about these terms it will help me in reading the research paper comfortably, I am not a professor or anything, I am an undergraduate student.

Comment: I suspect that it's not only related to astronomy, but instead that astronomers have borrowed robust techniques from mathematicians. So it is likely to be of general use. But for reading the paper you mentioned, it is ***then*** that you will need to know how it is that astronomers have chosen to cross-pollinate themselves from outside fields in order to understand their paper. It's still a math technique, but the meaning of "pseudo data" in astronomy is probably a deduction into astronomical specifics. So that's why I pointed you in that direction.

Comment: A related topic area appears to be [here in Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)), which discusses LOOCV. It appears that problems related to applying LOOCV have forced astronomers to find other approaches that are "good enough" for their uses with variable stars. So that's why I think it's not sufficient to just read some math paper on the topic. Just as you wouldn't want to read a math paper on group theory and complex numbers if you wanted to understand how electronics designers use \$j\omega\$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due the extreme low SNR of observations of millions of new stars with new satellite telescopes, plotting the motion and distance of new stars by the pulsing periods of faint light, the wavelength shifts and the phase, many periods are unknown or not exactly or just sometimes periodic hence pseudo-periodic.

There are many gravitational influences to consider such as the attraction forces of black holes and the centripetal forces of possible planets.  It has been found on our solar system that moons are phase and frequency locked to the planet’s rotational frequency such that the only one side of the moon is visible from the surface if they rotate at the same fundamental frequency. It is known that there are over 200 moons in our planetary system and many are retrograde and have become synchronous to the hosting planet’s rotational frequency by x1 like earth is moon, or 1x,2x, 4x. Many are not perfect orbits and the mass of the moon can wobble a distant planet’s orbit, just as Uranus, the largest planet is almost synchronized to the solar flare 11 yr cycle, which also have many longer cycles up to thousands of years suggesting how solar flares are modulated in their eruptions by external forces. This is an example how distant stars can be modulated in their emissions. It is far more complex than simply Keppler’s Law.

Once the mechanism of the modulations are discovered, then the periodic emissions of stars can be understood, or visa versa by simulated models, such as which ones might inhabit an earth like planet with an exquisite balance of energy to support life with cycles of temperature that are near 0’C to sustain  all the other cycles of life, water content and gas cycles from plants.  The stability of nature has so many exponential powers of balance, it is even far greater than the stability of an atomic clock. Yet modulation in climate change from atomic to organic to atmospheric to chemical to laws of physics that predicting the consequences of disturbances is a major concern by scientists in each field. It is so complex that divergent opinions exist on climate change that warming and cooling exponential and pseudo-periodic and periodic functions exist increase the apparent modulation of temperature extremes that can cause polar ice to melt at alarming rates with snow in Texas in the spring and conflicting theories about carbon cycles.

There are possibly many fields of science explored with pseudo-periodic functions like Schumann resonance of the magnetosphere that are impulse triggered by solar X flares and the global consciousness of similar emitted brain wave cycles as well as the known diurnal effects of light.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo periodic functions of n independent variables are functions that show a certain periodicity in the phase space.

Think about Earth that orbits around Sun.

Earth's trajectory, thought as a vector T(x,y,z,t), changes in space year by year but it has a period that oscillates around 365*24*60*60 seconds.